# Send PHP variable value to input tag using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I took data from form then put that in Javascript variable then add it and put it back in php variable to print it. I am learning php and wanted to use javascript and php together.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['submit'])){

        $firstName = $_GET['firstValue'];
        $secondName = $_GET['secondValue'];

        echo"
            <script>
                let firstValue = $firstName, 
                secondValue = $secondName;

                $result = firstValue + secondValue;

                document.getElementById('result').value  = $result;
            </script>
        ";
        
        
    }
?>
    <form method="get">

    <input type="number" name="firstValue"> 
    <input type='number' name='secondValue'>

    <input type = 'number' id='result'/> /* I want to put result in this input tag. */

    <input type="submit" value="click" name='submit'> /*Submit button*/
</form>
```

I was getting error that result variable undefined but why??

To remove error i removed $result variable and try putting value directly in input tag.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['submit'])){

        $firstName = $_GET['firstValue'];
        $secondName = $_GET['secondValue'];

        echo"
            <script>
                let firstValue = $firstName, 
                secondValue = $secondName;

                document.getElementById('result').value  = firstValue + secondValue;

            </script>
        ";
        
        
    }
?>
    <form method="get">

    <input type="number" name="firstValue"> 
    <input type='number' name='secondValue'>

    <input type = 'number' id='result'/> /* I want to put result in this input tag. */

    <input type="submit" value="click" name='submit'> /*Submit button*/
</form>
```

Now no error but code is still not working.

Comment: you could use AJAX

Comment: It seems the `<input>` value could be populated directly by PHP. Is there a reason you're using JavaScript?

Comment: You never assigned the PHP variable `$result`. That should be a JavaScript variable.

Comment: The problem in the second version is that the JavaScript is before the HTML elements, so `document.getElementById('result')` doesn't find the element. Aren't you getting an error in the browser console?

Comment: I know we can but i wanted to learn if javascript and php can work together @showdev

Comment: I certainly hope that when you're trying to debug JavaScript problems you have Developer Tools open.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar the problem is solved actually i was using replit rather than running xampp because it crashes a lot. second thing is that replit was refreshing answer again and again after pressing submit button. I am not going to use it from now.

Comment: XAMPP doesn't crash a lot. Probably there's some issue with your install. Try re-installing from scratch

Comment: @ADyson if i mistakenly turn of my pc when xampp is running then it stop working and give error "Unexpected shutdown". Something like that. I lost my complete database 3 times.